# how to show the date obtain from the kinect

Tags: openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,
I have installed openni_kinect in linux(Ubuntu 10.4  Ros),it works fine,but I don't know how to obtain the data of the kinect.
I need to complete a local path planning of the robot,using kinect to identify the obstacles around the robot,who can help me to solve this problem?
Thank you very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64268/how-to-show-the-date-obtain-from-the-kinect/) by [Mrs Wang](https://answers.ros.org/users/5047/mrs-wang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-06-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on 2013-06-04**:
the date ? Do you mean the time stamp ?

**Comment by [Mrs Wang](https://answers.ros.org/users/5047/mrs-wang/) on 2013-06-04**:
No, the date of the feature of the obstalces, I don't know what the kinect could obtain from the image~~

**Comment by [Philip](https://answers.ros.org/users/4292/philip/) on 2013-06-04**:
I read "date" as "data" :-)

**Comment by [Mrs Wang](https://answers.ros.org/users/5047/mrs-wang/) on 2013-06-04**:
It's my error,do you know how to get the data from the kinect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Data is published in multiple topics. Go through this link to understand various topics on which kinect publishes data. You can use rviz to to visualize the data.
http://ros.org/wiki/openni_camera
http://ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_bringup/Tutorials/groovy/3D%20Visualisation

If you want to avoid obstacles then try gmapping with kinect. http://ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Build%20a%20map%20with%20SLAM

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mrs Wang](https://answers.ros.org/users/5047/mrs-wang/) on 2013-06-04**:
Thank you very much, could you give me a method to contact you, I am a newer in kinect, if I have some other problems, I hope you could help me~~~